Differences between two definitions of Hodge polygons.
In Ben Moonen's book (15.16), they define the Hodge polygon as the ''slopes'' of the Frobenius action on a given basis. That is, for any $\sigma$-$F$-crystal $M$, where $\sigma$ is the Frobenius on $W(k)$, the Hodge slopes $r_i$ are defined as the elements satisfying $F(e_i)=p^{r_i}f_i$ for some series of basis $\{e_i\}$ and $\{f_i\}$.
However, in some other materials, like Conrad's book Definition 8.1.1, they define the Hodge slopes as the indexes of nonzero parts of a graded structure.
My question is, what's the relationship between these two definitions? It seems that the first definition does not require any graded structure, while the second one does not use the Frobenius endomorphism.
